# How to share RDD in concurrent Spark jobs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrency, future

Is there a way to use the same RDD in two concurrent Spark jobs?

For example, in the following application I am trying to write `b` to disk (job 1) while `f` is computed (job 2). However, Spark seems to execute only one job at a time.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val a = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000)
val b = a.mapPartitions(it => { Thread.sleep(5000); it })

// Compute b
b.persist().foreachPartition(_ => {})

val c = b.mapPartitions(it => { Thread.sleep(5000); it })
val d = c.mapPartitions(it => { Thread.sleep(5000); it })
val e = d.mapPartitions(it => { Thread.sleep(5000); it })
val f = e.mapPartitions(it => { Thread.sleep(5000); it })

// Concurrent actions on b and f (f uses b)
val actionFuts = List(
    // Job 1
    Future {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        b.saveAsTextFile("output.ignore/test/b.txt")
    },
    // Job 2
    Future {
        f.saveAsTextFile("output.ignore/test/f.txt")
    }
)

Await.result(Future.sequence(actionFuts).map(_ => ()), Duration.Inf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I am launching spark-submit with 4 workers, and the rdd `b` has 4 partitions. So, all the workers are busy and Spark can only execute one job (with 4 partitions, one per worker) at a time.

In order to execute both jobs at the same time, I have to use more workers or fewer partitions.